# How to debug "instance method 'adnw_URLEncodedString' conflicts" error?

Tags: ios, facebook, debugging, conflict

I am getting the following warning when I compile my app with Xcode 11:

> ld: warning: instance method 'adnw_URLEncodedString' in category from
>   /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-evxdjsslmaznvcdhgkuqnuyetuyc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp_lto.o
>   conflicts with same method from another category

I have made sure not to include any ".m" files. I searched the internet extensively to try to figure out where the "adnw_URLEncodedString" method is originating, to no avail.

What is the proper way to go about debugging this warning message?

UPDATE:
By process of elimination (removing frameworks and their corresponding code, and re-compiling the app): it has something to do with FBAudienceNetwork working in conjunction with FBSDKCoreKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issues section in the changelog under 5.6.0 --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-ios#5_6_0

> There is a conflicting instance method 'adnw_URLEncodedString' that is
>   present in two different categories. There will not be any side
>   effects as the implementation of this method is identical in both
>   places. There is a warning indicating this issue when building in Xcode, it is safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked for how to debug, here's a solution that worked for me:
This issue can be resolved by clearing out the derived data.

XCode -> File -> Workspace Settings. 
Click on the small grey arrow next to derived data. 
Then delete the folder applicable to your app project.

Do a Product Clean Build Folder and next time you compile you won't see that warning again.

Comment: This did not work for me, even after several tries. But thank you for presenting the solution that worked for you!